# typo3 backend does not parse: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS)

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I just installed Yet Another Gallery 4.0.7 on Typo3 6.2.19. When I try to open backend module I only get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /var/www/clients/client6/web32/web/typo3conf/ext/pt_extlist/Classes/Domain/Configuration/Filters/FilterConfig.php on line 351

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The error is coming from the extension "List Generator". The code uses the Class::class syntax which is probably not supported by your version of PHP. Check if you are running PHP 5.5 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to call class like:

```
'Vendor\YourController\Task\Yourclass'
```

, instead of

```
\Vender\YourController\Task\YourClass::class
```